# Determine type of child class with baseclass pointer

Tags: c++

Is there a way to determine the type of a child class with a baseclass pointer?

I have declared a pointer in a class constructor like this
in .h file

```
baseclass *screen;
```

in constructor

```
screen = new childclass();
```

Lets say baseclass has 5 different child classes and in my program I switch my pointer around to point towards various child objects, how can I determine the type of the object that screen is currently pointing towards?

Comment: In C++ variables have types, and values do not, so any way of achieving what you want is going to be dirty, and the fact that you want to achieve it reveals some class hierarchy design problem.

Comment: Why would you do that, rather than somehow relying on polymorphism to do the job of "behaving accordingly with the underlying type"?

Comment: Maybe it's bad design but it's for a small game with different screens, every screen is child class to a base screen class, and in my "game" class I have a screen object called activescreen that I point to different child objects depending on which different part of the game I want to draw.

Comment: _"Maybe it's bad design..."_ - no it **is** a bad design. When a base class must have explicit knowledge of classes that derive from it there is a flaw in the design.

Answer (score 7):

**Don't.**

Use virtual dispatch to achieve different behaviours for different derived types.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare typeid's: typeid(somepointer) == typeid(someclass) to find out what actual object was instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it. But as many others have suggested, it's not the right way to do it. Derived classes should handle the different behaviors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    virtual void func();
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    virtual void func(){
        return;
    }
};

class AnotherDerived : public Base{
public:
    virtual void func(){
        return;
    }
};

int main(){
    Base *dp = new Derived;
    Base *adp = new AnotherDerived;
    cout << typeid(*dp).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(*adp).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```